# when changing value of copied variable it is also changing main variable value in angularjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, foreach, reference

I am in a strange condition. I have an array of objects, I used angular.forEach to modify each object price key value but when I am changing it in each it is also changing main array object as well.

Have a look on code, you will understand then what I am trying to say.

```
var option_1_val = $scope.options.option_1_val;
        var option_2_val = $scope.options.option_2_val;
        console.log('genies',sc.genies);

        var new_arr = [];
        var each ;
        each = sc.genies;
        angular.forEach(each,function(val,key){
            var ob = {};
            ob = val;

            var priceA = angular.fromJson(ob.price);
            console.log('price',priceA);            

            var option = option_1_val.replace(" ","-")+","+option_2_val.replace(" ","-");
            console.log(option);

            ob.price = priceA[option];

            console.log(ob);
            new_arr.push(ob);
        });

option = 'Non-Vegetarian,' (after calculating)

sc.genies = [{"gs_id":"3","user_id":"25","service_id":"7","price":"{\"Vegetarian,Bengali\":\"200\",\"Vegetarian
,Chinese\":\"3100\",\"Vegetarian,Gujarati\":\"800\",\"Vegetarian,Italian\":\"100\",\"Vegetarian,Maharashtrian
\":\"100\",\"Vegetarian,Punjabi\":\"100\",\"Vegetarian,-South-Indian\":\"300\",\"Vegetarian,Thai\":\"100
\",\"Non-Vegetarian,Bengali\":\"1100\",\"Non-Vegetarian,Chinese\":\"3100\",\"Non-Vegetarian,Gujarati
\":\"100\",\"Non-Vegetarian,Italian\":\"100\",\"Non-Vegetarian,Maharashtrian\":\"100\",\"Non-Vegetarian
,Punjabi\":\"100\",\"Non-Vegetarian,-South-Indian\":\"80\",\"Non-Vegetarian,Thai\":\"100\",\"Jain,Bengali
\":\"2100\",\"Jain,Chinese\":\"2100\",\"Jain,Gujarati\":\"4100\",\"Jain,Italian\":\"100\",\"Jain,Maharashtrian
\":\"100\",\"Jain,Punjabi\":\"100\",\"Jain,-South-Indian\":\"800\",\"Jain,Thai\":\"100\"}","min_price"
:"80","max_price":"4100","username":"abdul quadir","email":"abdul.quadir@kiozen.com","rating":"3"}]
```

now when I am repeating sc.genie, I have taken it in a new variable already "each" and then I am changing "**price**" key of each array to undefined but *strange* point is when I see in console value of price in sc.genies is also changed to "undefined". Huh!

I hope you got my point, please help me why is that happening.

Thanks

Comment: Both each and sc.genies refers to same object. Create a copy by `var each = angular.copy(sc.genies);` and then do whatever you want to do with your `each` object, without affecting `sc.genies`.

Comment: This can be shortened from `var ob = {}; ob = val;` to `var ob = val;`. There is no need to declare the variable and then immediatelly to overwite it ...

Answer (score 7):

You should use `angular.copy` then when change in each value not affect to original value. because of `angular.copy` assign old value in new variable without reference.

like:

```
var each ;
each = angular.copy(sc.genies);
```

instead of

```
each = sc.genies;
```

Comment: perfect. this is working now :) but I want to know why it happens in angularjs while it does not happen in javascript

Comment: well, when you assigned one variable value in another variable then also keep previous reference with new one that's why when changing new assigned variable value then change referenced variable value. when using `angular.copy` then create new variable without reference.

Answer (score 5):

There is a simple answer. The reason why "both" values changes, is because it is actually the same object. The variable `val` from this line `angular.forEach(each,function(val,key){ ...` contains a pointer to an object. It is not another object. It is the same object, it is only accessed via different variable name.

If you really want the `original` and `working copy` to be different objects, then you need to manually create new instance with the same values.

You can create copy of an object like this (good for simple objects):

```
 var copy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(originalObject));
```

or as pointed in the comment above, you can use `angular.copy(source, destination)`. See the documentation https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy